# Internet working on Ubuntu, not on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, router, internet-connection

The following is the situation - I have an ADSL router with both ethernet and wifi interaces. I also have access to two dual-boot machines (with Windows 7 and Ubuntu Lucid). A few days back, the phone lines went down and the internet stopped working. Even after the phone lines started working, the internet remained down(or so I thought). However, I today noticed that internet is accessible on Ubuntu, but not Windows. I tried resetting the router, using the ethernet interface, but internet is not accessible on both machines on Windows.

I have also noticed that ping times to the router are very high from Windows but not from Ubuntu, even when using the ethernet interface (in the order of several  hundred ms). I suspect some routing trouble therefore, but am not positive. Also, for some reason my ISP guys ask me to change TCP MTU from 1500 to 1492 bytes, which might be the cause of the trouble.

Can somebody help me here?

Here is the output of `route PRINT` from one of the machines (192.168.1.1 is the router, 192.168.1.3* are client machines):

```
===========================================================================

Interface List
 15...00 1e 4c dc 3f 5f ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 13...00 1c bf 8b 55 99 ......Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
 12...00 23 ae b4 f1 b4 ......Broadcom NetLink (TM) Fast Ethernet
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3

===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table

===========================================================================

Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask     Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.33     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.33    281
     192.168.1.33  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.33    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.33    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.33    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.33    281

===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:

  Network Address          Netmask Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default

===========================================================================


IPv6 Route Table

===========================================================================

Active Routes:

 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    281 fe80::d50f:a099:a9bc:3d99/128 On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    281 ff00::/8                 On-link

===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:

  None
```

Comment: Unless you have a real desire for it, I would uncheck IPv6 in each of my network connections. That alone might solve it. For now, that is just a guess...it is works, I will change it to an answer.

Comment: @KCotreau:If you mean unchecking the IPv6 box at the place where we can change IP addresses, it did not work. If something else, please clarify.

Comment: I have to wonder if your network card was not damaged in the power outage. Do an ipconfig and see if you can ping your router/gateway address. Then see if you can ping 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS server), then see if you can ping www.google.com or www.cisco.com. Post back what can, and cannot, do.

Comment: How to determine and to recover from Winsock2 corruption in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, and in Windows Vista
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259

Try the following command: netsh winsock /reset

Comment: @KCotreau:The same network card works with Ubuntu, so I don't think there is any problem with the hardware. I can't perform non-subnet pings from Windows, or do nslookups (either through ISP servers or through the router).

Comment: @apoorv020 I did not realize they were the same computer, same network card. I don't know what the difference would be between how they behave, but I have seen weird things happen with routers...partially dying, but not all the way. I would either try a different router if you have one, or hook it up directly to your Internet connection...I would suspect that router.